# Is it possible to derive a DataGridView Column such that it can store an object of any sort?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a DataGridView that loads information from files and stores that information. The information is kept in a class form for use so I was thinking rather than have to reconstruct that class object from the data stored in the DGV, it would be easier to just save the class object into a column and access that object from that column when necessary. Is that possible? Would it have to do with DataBinding?

So ultimately what I would like is to be able to is this:

```
DataGridView DGV = new DataGridView;
//Initialization Stuff

DGV.Rows[0].Columns["objectColumn"].value = <ANY OBJECT OR CLASS TYPE AT ALL HERE>
```

Of course the column would be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridViewCell.Value` is of type `Object` which means you can store any object inside it. If your class overrides `ToString` method and provides a meaningful implementation it will be displayed in the respective cell.

If you don't override the `ToString` you can still use [DataGridView.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to format your object.

Comment: So I would be able to, say, take a DataGridView TextBox column, hide it, set it's value to whatever I felt like, and then retrieve it to a later date so long as I cast it as the proper type?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Try it out.

Comment: Excellent thats what I needed to be certain of thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If that helped consider marking it as answer, If you need more help leave a comment below.

Comment: I was gonna :P Just had to wait for sufficient time to elapse and someone to remind me.